# How to intercept keyboard strokes going to Java Swing JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jtextfield

The JTextField is a calculator display initialized to zero and it is bad form to display a decimal number with a leading 0 like 0123 or 00123. The numeric buttons (0..9) in a NetBeans Swing JFrame use append() [below] to drop the leading zeros, but the user may prefer the keyboard to a mouse, and non-numeric characters also need to be handled.

```
private void append(String s) {
    if (newEntry) {
        newEntry = false;
        calcDisplay.setText(s);
    } else if (0 != Float.parseFloat(calcDisplay.getText().toString())) {
        calcDisplay.setText(calcDisplay.getText().toString() + s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could restrict the characters input to the JTextField by adding a custom KeyListener.  Here is a quick example to demonstrate the idea:

```
myTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    char c = e.getKeyChar();
    if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
      e.consume(); // Stop the event from propagating.
    }
  }
});
```

Of course, you need to consider special keys like Delete and combinations like CTRL-C, so your KeyListener should be more sophisticated.  There are probably even freely available utilities to do most of the grunt work for you.

Comment: The DocumentFilter suggestion is the way to go. This was added to Swing in JDK4 and is the preferred approach over using KeyEvents. Your comment about CTRL-C is one of the reasons a filter is better.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `DocumentFilter`.

(Edit: This answer originally included a ling to a simple complete example program on my now defunct weblog.)

Comment: Tom. The link is a bit hard to read as one long unformatted line.

Comment: Trying to read it as a Windows text file? I think WordPad should handle it, but Notepad will not. Chrome on Windows shows it correctly; IE does not. I would link to the weblog entry which describes it, but I can't find that in google (probably jroller being flaky).