# How do I create a JTextField that ignores user input but lets components modify text?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Here's what I'd like as a proof of concept: I want a Frame with a text field and a button on it.  Anything the user types into the text field is ignored, but if you click the button, it sets the text on the text field.  How would you do this?

I've done some research ahead of time and come up with a solution that I'll post as an answer.  But my concern is that there's a much easier way to do this.  I'm asking the question to find out if there's a better way.

Here's a screenshot of the reason I'm trying to build this proof of concept:

[image: capture key inputs]

I'm trying to build something just like this.  When user enters text, I want to ignore what they are saying, capture it, and put my own interpretation.  For example, if the user pressed <kbd>control+Y</kbd>, I want it to say this:

[image: key input captured]

I don't want to simply make the JTextField un-editable, because that grays out the box and hides the cursor.  I want people to know they should click on the text field and type.

Comment: A text field won't receive "control" keystrokes, only keystrokes that generate key typed events. Maybe instead you could have a couple of checkboxes (Control, Alt, Shift) and a combo box containing a-z, 0-9. As the use makes a selection you do your translation and display the result in a JLabel.

Comment: @camickr yes, but I've already figured that detail out.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to maintain the cursor, you can intercept the keystrokes as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3622506/1601122).

Code from above link:

```
myTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        char c = e.getKeyChar();
        if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
            e.consume(); // Stop the event from propagating.
        }
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can disable entry and then restore the background color easily enough, but lose the cursor:

```
textField.setEditable(false);
textField.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: Re: your first example, it's my understanding that that will not catch Control+V (paste) and would end up displaying the clipboard.  The second is alright, but without a cursor, I think it will confuse users.

Comment: Because of the nature of event notification, this may not work for all p,at forms and isn't a recommend way for intercepting input

Comment: Agreed. The DocumentFilter is the correct approach, but per tieTYL's answer, it seems alternatives are being sought.

Answer (score 2):

Make the text field non-editable. The user can't enter data, but the program still can:

```
textField.setEditable(false);
```

Comment: I don't like how that greys out the text field and hides the cursor.  I'll update my question to be more specific

Answer (score 2):

This is an edited version of [hendalst' code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534703/how-do-i-create-a-jtextfield-that-ignores-user-input-but-lets-components-modify/16534958#16534958). It also prevents things like **Ctrl+V** because the event is also consumed in the `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` methods.

```
myTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
        ke.consume();
        // do what you want:
        myTextField.setText(...);
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
        ke.consume();
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
        ke.consume();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet of code does exactly what I want.  But I'm hoping there's an easier way:

```
package com.sandbox;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JTextField text = new JTextField();
        ((AbstractDocument) text.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
            @Override
            public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
//                super.remove(fb, offset, length);
            }

            @Override
            public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
//                super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
            }

            @Override
            public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
//                super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
            }
        });

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        panel.setLayout(layout);

        panel.add(text);
        JButton jButton = new JButton("Click to change text");
        jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DocumentFilter old = ((AbstractDocument) text.getDocument()).getDocumentFilter();
                ((AbstractDocument) text.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter());
                text.setText("You clicked!");
                ((AbstractDocument) text.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(old);
            }
        });
        panel.add(jButton);

        frame.setContentPane(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```